# In printf ( "%d", 5 ); is 5 stored in the memory?

Tags: c, memory, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* func ();
int main ( )
{
   char *p;
   p=func();
   printf("%c",*p);
}
char* func()
{

    return "hello";
}
```

Here, printf prints "h", which means that a pointer to "hello" is created and that the string "hello" is stored in memory. 
Similarly, in printf ( "%d", 5 ), is '5' stored in the memory?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: That '5' in printf is given a memory or not?

Comment: that `return "hello"` is invalid as it is not a given any memory, you just write it... Somewhere in the heap. if you try to `printf` the whole string now, it might as well fail and/or print some other characters.

Comment: @JanLegner: It's invalid but not for the reason you cite. It's invalid because implicit conversion of a string literal to `char*` was removed in C++11. Implicit conversion to `char const*` is still there, though, so the fix is easy.

Comment: No,it does print the whole string too.But my question is something else.I used this code just to prove that the string literal is given a memory.That is why pointer points to its base address.Iwant to know if '5' in printf is given a memory or not.If it is,then where?If not then why?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You are right of course.

Comment: @JanLegner: Well possibly not any longer, since the programming language was changed from C++ to C. I don't know the rules of modern C here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is extremely platform dependent, but most sane compilers shouldn't store `5` in any data section of your code, read only or otherwise -- it should be simply pushed on the stack before the `printf` call.

Edit: I actually just checked, and GCC does something even more interesting:
[image]

It avoids the stack entirely on a 64-bit machine and uses straight registers because of the multitude available. It still doesn't store the `5` anywhere but in the opcode itself.

Comment: @JashanSingh In C, string literals don't have type `const char`. In C++ they do.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but the literal *is* in a read only data section, and `5` *isn't*

Comment: Could you please explain the Assembly output.I don't know assembly language.

Comment: It's basically just setting up the `call printf` by `mov`ing `5` in `esi` and the string pointer in `edi`. The rest is just boilerplate that disappears if I compile with -Os, I forgot to do it for this.

Comment: Now that I look at it I'm surprised it chose to move 0 in `eax` instead of just `xor`ing it with itself. I thought that was universally accepted as better.

Answer (score 2):

What you are printing is just a character in order to print out the whole string stored in the memory location

```
printf("%s",p);
```

`%s` format specifier makes sure that the characters are printed until a `\0` character is found

Comment: I know that.I just wanted to prove that the string literal is stored in a memory.But how can i check if '5' is given a memory or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure check the adsembler language output of your compiler.

Most probably an integer literal in a function call will be placed on the stack with a single operation. You can access the memory adress of the 5 from within the called function (i.e. printf), but when the fuction returns it will be popped off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>After this answer was posted the question was changed from C++ to C. I'm not going to chase a changing question, but I'm leaving this answer as-is because it might useful to readers.</sup>

In the statement

```
printf( "%d", 5 );
```

the arguments after the format string are passed as C *variadic argument*, specified by three periods `...` in the formal argument list. This means that no particular types are <sup>1</sup>expected as far as the compiler is concerned, except that non-POD class type actual arguments are not permitted. It also means that before they're passed, the values are **promoted** to a smaller set of types, for integers usually up to `int`, and for floating point up to `double`.

The `5` will typically be part of a machine code instruction that pushes that value on the machine's runtime stack.

As part of an instruction it is in “memory”, but it needs not be a separate part that can be easily accessed as that number value, and it needs not even be the ordinary data memory where C++ objects reside (some micro-controllers use Harvard architecture with separate code and data memories, and possibly, but I don't know, they have C++ compilers).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) Smart compilers can know about common standard library functions such as `printf`, and interpret format strings, etc. E.g. g++ does that. In the old C times that was the function of a separate program called `lint`.</sup>

Comment: Look again--this a C question.

Comment: @MikeHousky: You mean, it *now* is a C question. It was a C++ question when this answer was posted. I'm not going to chase a changing question, but thanks! -- I was about to post the C++ standard's wording about the argument type promotions, and now I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between 5 and "hello" is that "hello" is an array, so that it is passed as an argument and returned as a result in pointer form (as a pointer to the first element).  An int argument to a function, like `printf`, is passed by value, and the memory may only exist during the function call.

The compiled code may (and usually will) just push a constant 5 onto the stack for that argument.  There's memory, alright, but it's a bit field in the machine instruction and not a data word.

If you have a debugger, it might be interesting for you to disassemble the code at the call to see what I mean.  On an x86 processor, for example, the opcode names are easy enough to pick out approximatly what's going on.

In that `printf` call, you'll see that the format string is pushed as a pointer to the stored string in constant data memory, but the 5 will probably be an "immediate" push of the value 5. ("Immediate" data in assembly means the value is in the instruction itself, and not fetched separately from data memory.)

The bottom line is that the memory for that 5 is only guaranteed to exist on the stack during the execution of the function.